# How would I check the file size of the uncompressed tar file without extracting

Tags: tar

I downloaded a 16GB tar file named "SetA.tar", but I would like to know how much space the uncompressed file would take up on my disk. How would I find that?

Comment: `tar -tvf SetA.tar`

Answer (score 1):

**.tar**

Use 
`tar -tvf SetA.tar` to list all the files in the archive, to get the total size of the `.tar` pipe the result to [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to sum the total bytes;

```
tar -tvf SetA.tar | awk '{s+=$5} END{print (s/1024/1024), "MB"}'
```

- `-t` List archive contents to stdout
- `-v` Verbose
- `-f` file path

---

---

**.tar.gz**

You could use `gzip -l SetA.tar`. Man page;

> -l, --list        This option displays information about the file's compressed and **uncompressed size**, ratio, uncompressed name.  With the -v option, it also displays the compression
>                          method, CRC, date and time embedded in the file.

```
$ gzip -l sample.tar.gz
  compressed uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
       91700       522240  82.4% sample.tar
```

Comment: Hint: `tar`!=`tar.gz`

Comment: Oeps, thought the question was about a `tar.gz`, please see my edit!

Answer (score 0):

A tar file is not compressed. Therefore if SetA.tar is 16GB then it will use an additional 16GB if you extract everything.